# Get JSON data into TVML prohect without JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, tvos, tvjs

I have a working code to get data from JSON and use it with JQuery.
Can I do it without JQuery? How can I do it?

```
 function performRequest(type, route, data) {
        return $.ajax({
            type: type,
            dataType: 'json',
            url:  '...' + route,
            data: data
        });
    }

    function getChannels() {
        log(' > get channels');
        return performRequest('GET', 'channel/list', {id: browserId}).then(function (response) {
            response.data.forEach(function (channel) {
                channels[channel.id] = channel;
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using XMLHttpRequest? Like this - works on aTV2/3...

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (req.readyState==4)  // 4: request is complete
    {
        data = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
    }
};
req.open('GET', url, true);  // true: asynchronous
req.send();
```